# react native firebase phone authentication - very strange behavior

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, react-native, react-native-firebase

Ive copied the code for phone auth from RNFB pretty much exactly from their site...see code below (link [here](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth)).
When I run code using the "Phone numbers for testing" functionalty provided by Firebase (i.e. use a dummy phone number)....then it does NOT create a user in FB when I run the `signInWithPhoneNumber` function.....and its not until I run `confirmCode` function that it creates the user in FB.  As I understand it, thats the way its suppposed to work.
HOWEVER....when I run `MyPhoneAuthButton` fn using my own phone number (i.e. a "real" test)...then the SMS auth message is sent to me and the **user is created immediately in FB without having to run `confirmCode` fn**.
Why is it acting differently when testing vs running in prod?  Which process should I be coding for?
Any help appreciated

```
const MyPhoneAuthButton = props => {
  const [objConfirm, setObjConfirm] = useState(null);
  const [code, setCode] = useState('');

  // Handle the button press
  const signInWithPhoneNumber = phoneNumber => {
    auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
      .then(confirmResult => {
        setObjConfirm(confirmResult);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Invalid Phone Number', err.message);
      });
  };

  const confirmCode = () => {
    objConfirm
      .confirm(code)
      .then(user => {
        console.log('User auth by phone OK', user);
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Invalid code.', err.message);
      });
  };


  <MyButton
    onPress={() => {
      signInWithPhoneNumber(props.telNum);
    }}>
    Sign in With Phone Number
  </MyButton>

  const signInWithPhoneNumber = phoneNumber => {
    auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
      .then(confirmResult => {
        console.log('User successfully authorized via telNum');
        setObjConfirm(confirmResult);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        Alert.alert('Invalid Phone Number', err.message);
        console.log('Invalid Phone Number', err.message);
      });
  };
```

Comment: can you link the url you took the code from? I'd like to double check something

Comment: Done - added to original post.  Only thing I changed was to use `.then()` rather than `async await`.....as using `async await` it was not allowing me to `catch` errors

Comment: did u render the confirm button? Can u show your render function

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: Hi @jamesmurphy, you don't call confirmCode function anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

It should be like that. You should pass the confirmation phase firstly, then you will have the button for code confirmation. I have reorganized it according to the url you linked from firebase

```js
const MyPhoneAuthButton = props => {
  const [objConfirm, setObjConfirm] = useState(null);
  const [code, setCode] = useState('');

  // Handle the button press
  const signInWithPhoneNumber = phoneNumber => {
    auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
      .then(confirmResult => {
        setObjConfirm(confirmResult);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Invalid Phone Number', err.message);
      });
  };

  const confirmCode = () => {
    objConfirm
      .confirm(code)
      .then(user => {
        console.log('User auth by phone OK', user);
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Invalid code.', err.message);
      });
  };
  
  const signInWithPhoneNumber = phoneNumber => {
    auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
      .then(confirmResult => {
        console.log('User successfully authorized via telNum');
        setObjConfirm(confirmResult);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        Alert.alert('Invalid Phone Number', err.message);
        console.log('Invalid Phone Number', err.message);
      });
  };

  if(!objConfirm) {
    return (
      <MyButton
        onPress={() => {
          signInWithPhoneNumber(props.telNum);
        }}>
        Sign in With Phone Number
      </MyButton>  
    )
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <TextInput value={code} onChangeText={text => setCode(text)} />
      <Button title="Confirm Code" onPress={() => confirmCode()} />
    </>
  );
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense to me....please clairfy how this is a solution?  Appears that all youve done is duplicated the `signInWithPhoneNumber` function and removed a console log and an alert.  Perhaps Im missing something??

Comment: Yes, you miss. There are 2 states for which button should appear. The first one is it controls if objConfirm, if it is not confirmed it renders the button for signing, else if it is already confirmed, it will render textinput and button which enables typing code and submit. I have just compared the code you wrote and the code you linked and answered with coding the missing parts.

Comment: I did write the code that renders different button based on type.....I just didnt indlude in my question as I didnt believe it to be relevant/important.  The question I am looking to be answered is why the behavior is different when I use a real number instead of a dummy one